# Display next set of words in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, string.format

I have the following code:

```
 int numberOfWords = 50;

 string regexMatch = string.Format(@"^(\w+\b.*?){{" + numberOfWords + "}}");
 string firstWords = Regex.Match(result, regexMatch).Value;
```

This code displays the first 50 words in a string. Now I want to display next 50 words (51st word to 100th word). How do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean next 50? You can create new varible like "counter" and put it into a loop, and multiply numberOfWords * counter (1st time couner will be 1, next time round will be 2 and so on....  ... { + numberOfWords * couner + "} ...

Comment: Accept an answer if your problem was solved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same regex but starting after first 5o words. As you have first 50 words in firstWords so we have to start after these fifty words. So we will take substring of the result after fifty words which we have in firstWords. firstWords.Length will become new starting point for regex for second 5o words.

```
 string secondWords = Regex.Match(result.Substring(firstWords.Length).Trim(), regexMatch).Value;
```

Comment: the string secondWords is having null value. What could be the reason?

Comment: I checked the problem was the space character on the start of string we left after first fifty words. by statement result.Substring(firstWords.Length) Now I removed that space and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match multiple `string`s,

Code Like this :

```
List<string> Words = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; (result.Length - (i * numberOfWords)) < numberOfWords; i++)
{
    Words.Add(Regex.Match(result.Substring(i * numberOfWords).Trim(), regexMatch).Value)
}
```

You get a List of the 50 words present in the string! However if at the end of the `string` there is less than 50 words it will not add the word those to the `Words` List.